# export asp.net page to word document

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, rtf, export-to-word

I need help in exporting an asp.net page to a word (rtf) format. It seems really simple but somehow I cannot seem to complete it. I do NOT need to download it, i just need to convert it at the back end without the user knowing it. Is it possible without using third party tools?

Comment: This question needs a little clarification, Are you saying you want to get a ASPX page from a URL and convert the HTML it ouputs to RTF?

Answer (score 1):

Change Response.ContentType to "application/msword"

Comment: Response.Buffer = True

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;Filename= temp.rtf")

            'Response.Write(sResponse)

            'Response.Flush()

Comment: The above code downloads the asp.net converted page. However I need to save it "on the server" without the user knowing anything about it. The response contenttype would actually tell the browser to show it to the user in word format. I do not want that

Comment: @Farax so you want to save a Word/RTF document to the server out of an ASP.NET page?

Comment: yup ... I use the normal stream writer to right the html which is generated from the ASP.NET page. When I open it from VS, it shows me all the html, when I copy it elsewhere, it opens correctly. I guess that was confusing me a bit